# Firebase basic promise returning

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-realtime-database

This is a pretty basic question, so I apologize in advance. But I have been struggling with this all night. I have a simple firebase database query... which I know works.. I use child_added so itll return a few times for each different node off of the spot I am querying.

I am then trying to compliment a callback after it is completely done calling. Right now it will return about 10 different values, so my goal is to then use a promise or some sort of callback to run code after the database reference is finished.

```
 var getIsStarred = getFirebase().database().ref('feed/value').on('child_added').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("JX10: ok")
  });

Promise.(getIsStarred).then(function(results) {
    console.log("JX10: end promise thing okay sick")
});
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: `itll return a few times for each different node` - you can't use a Promise, because a Promise can only be fulfilled exactly once ... does `.on('child_added')` even return a promise?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase's `on()` function docs are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on

As you can see, it wants a callback, and also returns the callback so that it can be used as a parameter to an `off()` call if desired. It doesn't look like a promise is returned anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to run an action after all children have been loaded. You'd do that with a `once('value'` handler:

```
var getIsStarred = getFirebase().database().ref('feed/value').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("the initial items have been loaded")
 });
```